# remoting vs socket

Tags: c#

what is the diff, advantage and disadvantage between remoting and socket... which is best way  for Server-Client functionality....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sockets are raw binary streams between two endpoints. You would need to wrap your own RPC (etc) layer to process the messages, and deal with a lot of infrastructure code. However, since they are so close to the metal this can be very, very efficient. It is not tied to any specific architecture, as long as both ends talk the same message format. Tools like protobuf-net can help you construct binary messages for streams (rather than rolling your own serialization code).

Remoting is a .NET specific tool, and is very brittle re versioning. I wouldn't recommend remoting for client/server - use things like WCF instead.

WCF is a more flexible comms stack - a lot of power and complexity, but arguably a bit of bloat too (xml, complex security etc). It is data-contract based, so *roughly* open (client/server can be different), but still a bit .NET focused.

---

**edit** For info, [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) provides an RPC stack too; at the moment there is only an HTTP implementation provided, but at some point I'll add raw TCP/IP.

Comment: And for "best"... depends on the requirements ;-p

Comment: +1 for WCF. And if you have non-.net clients use WCF to expose SOAP or REST web services. The case for pure remoting is rapidly disappearing.

Answer (score 3):

Direct socket manipulation can give you more power, flexibility, performance, and unfortunately complexity when compared to Remoting or WCF.  However, if you need the benefits of low-level TCP/IP, such as non-blocking IO and custom protocols, tools such as [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) and frameworks like [Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) can ease the complexity burden.  I recommend trying the higher-level APIs like WCF first and only use direct sockets if these don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I second most that Marc Gravell wrote - specifically remoting and internal serialization are "easy" but are very easy to break and often do not scale well to a public network (I'm not that familiar with .net remoting, but I guess it needs a well known registry service which is often problematic when going out of the clean lab environment).

Implementing a standard or even roll-your-own RPC is harder but safer in the long run: you do not have problems with code revisions (or they are easier to control), scaling is fully controlled by your own code, and its easy to develop components using various technologies.

There are many many many tools that help you easily build RPC mechanisms over sockets, but I really like to use plain old HTTP - get a simple HTTP embedded server running inside your server process and your client just needs to have an HTTP client to send messages. If you develop your own simple RESTful call semantics (instead of using some bloated message format like SOAP or XML-RPC), then there is really almost nothing to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that choosing between sockets and remoting you better consider on what type of  application you are developing. Sockets are definitely for your own protocol implementations, low level programming and the only way to go if you have to communicate to the other tcp/ip applications. Remoting is a preffered way to develop new .NET communication applications, where you don't need to come down to tcp/ip stack and ensure your application talks to the others (probably legacy applications). In case you could go only with .NET it's better to choose .NET 3.5 and WCF framework instead of .net 2.0 remoting, the last one is dead and unsupported technology.